# NSCoding unexpectedly finds nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject, nscoding

I have a problem that I can't think of any explanation for. I have an class defined below.

In the app delegate I call `EyeGamesPrefs.loadData()`, and it crashes at `watchList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("watchList") as! [Int]` saying it encountered a nil.

- If I take out the `watchList` variable, which is identical to the `selectedConsoleIndeces` variable, it works fine.
- If I change it to `watchList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("selectedConsoleIndeces") as! [Int]` it works fine.
- If I copy and paste the exact same code into a blank project, it works fine.
- It runs in the current project on the iPhone 5 simulator, but not on the iPhone 6 simulator. In a new project it runs on the 6.

Can anybody explain why `watchList` won't work but `selectedConsoleIndeces` does? The only difference is the name of the variable! And why would it work pasted into a different project but not in this one? It just doesn't make any sense.

```
class EyeGamesPrefs:NSObject,NSCoding {

// This is a shared instance available throughout the app
static var sharedInstance = EyeGamesPrefs()

// These are various preferences used thoughout the app
// They are saved and loaded from NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() when the app launches or goes into the background
// See the App Delegate
var colorScheme:        Int     // index of color scheme in listOfColorSchemes
var boughtRemoveAds:    Bool
var boughtSkins:        Bool
var watchedTutorial:    Bool
var selectedConsoleIndeces:   [Int]
var watchList: [Int]

override init() {
    colorScheme      = 0
    boughtRemoveAds  = false
    boughtSkins      = false
    watchedTutorial  = false
    selectedConsoleIndeces = Array(0...(50 - 1))
    watchList = Array(0...(50 - 1))
    super.init()
}

// What to do when this object is saved to NSUserDefaults
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(colorScheme, forKey: "colorScheme")
    aCoder.encodeObject(boughtRemoveAds, forKey: "boughtRemoveAds")
    aCoder.encodeObject(boughtSkins, forKey: "boughtSkins")
    aCoder.encodeObject(watchedTutorial, forKey: "watchedTutorial")
    aCoder.encodeObject(selectedConsoleIndeces, forKey: "selectedConsoles")
    aCoder.encodeObject(watchList, forKey: "watchList")
}

// What to do when this object is loaded from NSUserDefaults
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    colorScheme         = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("colorScheme") as! Int
    boughtRemoveAds     = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("boughtRemoveAds") as! Bool
    boughtSkins         = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("boughtSkins") as! Bool
    watchedTutorial     = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("watchedTutorial") as! Bool
    selectedConsoleIndeces    = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("selectedConsoles") as! [Int]
    watchList = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("watchList") as! [Int]
}



class func savePreferences() {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(EyeGamesPrefs.sharedInstance)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "preferences")
    NSLog("saved preferences")
}

class func loadPreferences() {
    if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("preferences") as? NSData {
        let prefs = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! EyeGamesPrefs
        EyeGamesPrefs.sharedInstance = prefs
        NSLog("loaded preferences")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that `selectedConsoleindeces` is decoding the object for the key "selectedConsoles" while `watchList` is looking for an object for the key "watchList" which is returning 'nil'. This means that there is no object with the key "watchList" in your **NSUserDefaults**.

You need to ensure there is an object for the key "watchList" and/or handle receiving nil values gracefully.

You can use the following code to print out the entire **NSUserDefaults** to verify if you have a key "watchList" and if so the variable associated with it:

```
println(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The value that gets written to NSUserDefaults is actually the sharedInstance object as serialized data (see the savePreferences function). If it didn't exist, the keyed unarchiver would never be called, so I'm sure it's there. I verified it using your tip as well. The problem must be in the unarchiving process.